# How to add New Excel Worksheet in the Right Click New context menu?

Tags: microsoft-excel

OS - Windows 7 (32-bit)
Office Version - 2013 Standard

Whenever I right click on a blank space in a folder, I see option to create a New Folder / New Word Document etc, but am not able to see a New Excel Workbook option. How can I get the option?

Answer (score 0):

1. Type regedit in RUN dialog box and press Enter. It'll open Registry Editor. Now expand "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" key.
2. Now look for the file type which you want to add in "New" menu, e.g. for adding MP3 file type look for .MP3 key.
3. Right-click on it and select "New -> Key" and give it name "ShellNew".
4. In right-side pane, right-click and select "New -> String Value". Give it name "NullFile" and press Enter.
5. That's it. You'll immediately get the file type entry in "New" menu.

Comment: I did all that, but no change in the menu